# Agrupar varias funciones con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hice este script en cual me piden que haga un modificacion de precios dependiendo si es mensual, trimestral y anual.

Pero no se como agrupar todo en un misma funcion y llamar un elemento `id` o `class` dentro del boton y no `onclick=""`

Quise crear tres variables, pero lo precions son dos y me devuelve un error porque no puedo colocar dos valores dentro de una variable o constante.

Este es el script:

```js
function valorMensual() { 
  valora.innerHTML="699";
  valorm.innerHTML="399";
}

function valorTrimestral() {
  valora.innerHTML="629.10";
  valorm.innerHTML="359.10";
}

function valorAnual() {
  valora.innerHTML="559.20";
  valorm.innerHTML="319.20";
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm pt-4" role="group">
<button id="cambiar" class="btn btn-light" onclick="valorMensual()">Mensual</button>
<button id="cambiar" class="btn btn-light" onclick="valorTrimestral()">Trimestral (10% off)</button>
<button id="cambiar" class="btn btn-light" onclick="valorAnual()">Anual (20% off)</button>
</div>

<h1>$<span id="valorm">399</span></h1>
<h1>$<span id="valora">699</span></h1>
```

Gracias!

Comment: No deberias tener `id's` repetidos. Los `ID` deben ser unicos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide los datos en un objeto, y por otro lado, separas la funcionalidad, quedando algo así:

```js
const valores = {
   mensual: {a: "699", m: "399"},
   trimestral: {a: "629.10", m: "359.10"},
   anual: {a: "559.20", m: "319.20"}
};
document.getElementById("grupoDeBotones")
        .onclick = (event) => {
   const elementId = event.target.id;

   if (elementId && valores[elementId]) {
       valora.innerHTML = valores[elementId].a;
       valorm.innerHTML = valores[elementId].m;
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="grupoDeBotones" class="btn-group btn-group-sm pt-4" role="group">
  <button id="mensual" class="btn btn-light">Mensual</button>
  <button id="trimestral" class="btn btn-light">Trimestral (10% off)</button>
  <button id="anual" class="btn btn-light">Anual (20% off)</button>
</div>
  
<h1>$<span id="valorm">399</span></h1>
<h1>$<span id="valora">699</span></h1>
```

En un inicio realicé la pregunta, con un onClick en los botones html, pero como dices que no quieres onclick ahí, lo puedes pasar a javascript.

Ahora si, ten en cuenta que SIEMPRE vas a necesitar el dato que llegue de algún sitio y momento, es decir, en que momento sabes que quieres mostrar el anual o el trimestral?

En ese punto es donde debes pasar los valores, sea de una forma u otra. Si es mediante otro evento, en ese evento debes capturar el id, poniendo el id específico como "key" del objeto de valores.

Espero que te ayude, saludos!

---

MODIFICACIÓN

He realizado una "demo" completa con todo el HTML, debería funcionarte.

Quizás te ha faltado por definir esta parte:

```
const valora = document.getElementById('valora');
const valorm = document.getElementById('valorm');
```

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  const valores = {
    mensual: {a: "699", m: "399"},
    trimestral: {a: "629.10", m: "359.10"},
    anual: {a: "559.20", m: "319.20"}
  };
  const valora = document.getElementById('valora');
  const valorm = document.getElementById('valorm');

  document.getElementById("grupoDeBotones")
    .onclick = (event) => {
    const elementId = event.target.id;

    if (elementId && valores[elementId]) {
      valora.innerHTML = valores[elementId].a;
      valorm.innerHTML = valores[elementId].m;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="grupoDeBotones" class="btn-group btn-group-sm pt-4" role="group">
  <button id="mensual" class="btn btn-light">Mensual</button>
  <button id="trimestral" class="btn btn-light">Trimestral (10% off)</button>
  <button id="anual" class="btn btn-light">Anual (20% off)</button>
</div>

<h1>$<span id="valorm">399</span></h1>
<h1>$<span id="valora">699</span></h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias Sergio, pero me sale un error en el servidor locas que dice" `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null` y no se ejecuta y aca si. Porque puede ser?

Comment: Has adaptado el HTML correctamente? La id "grupoDeBotones" que tiene la caja padre de todos los botones?`<div id="grupoDeBotones" class="btn-group btn-group-sm pt-4" role="group">` Por otra parte, fijate vien en que valores estás pasando a la función y como los obtienes. Guiate de `console.log()` para ver que te está regresando y debugear el punto en el que pierdes los datos o deja de funcionar

Comment: Habia hecho unos cambios y ahora lo copie tal cual y sigue con el error `document.getElementById(...) is null`

Comment: Tienes algún "document.ready, o window.ready" en tu javascript? Es posible que el contenido HTML no esté cargado justo cuando ejecutas tu función. El tema está en que algo tienes distinto. Utiliza el "console.log"p ara trazar el error linea a linea, variable a variable, Si eso te dice que te regresa null, es porque en tu HTML no existe la ID y por tanto no la encuentra

Comment: Estoy usando Bootstrap, puede ser eso o no se... no se como usar el console.log

Comment: El console.log(), es una función que te permite imprimir en la consola del navegador cualquier valor que introduzcas ahí. Es una forma de hacer debugging. He realizado una modificación en la respuesta, con un ejemplo completo con todo el html. Copialo entero y leelo linea a linea, adáptalo a tu código, debería funcionar. La parte del `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"..`, permite esperar a que el contenido esté cargado. Debería funcionar ;)

Comment: Entiendo, voy a investigar como usar `console.log()` y leer el codigo para entenderlo mejor. Muchas gracias!!